# Should Muslims study other cultures/religions in order to seek knowledge?

Tags: history, islamic-philosophy

Islam has given great importance to the process of seeking knowledge. We (Muslims) believe that  non muslims seeking knowledge  is very important, as it is the key element to find and follow the right path, but what about Muslims seeking knowledge of other religions? Is this seeking or research, allowed?

As Quran says:

> “Say: ‘Are those who know equal to those who know not?’ It is only men
>   of understanding who will remember (i.e. get a lesson from Allâh’s
>   Signs and Verses)”
>
> [**[al-Zumar 39:9]**](https://islamqa.info/en/10471)

For the sake of knowing this knowledge, ***Should Muslims study other religions or cultures, and should they also have to search the right sect in 73 sects?***  As Prophet SAWW said:

> My Ummah will be divided into 73 sects and only one will be the
>   righteous.
>    [1](http://sunniport.com/index.php?threads/hadith-of-73-sects-authentic.11867/page-2), [2](https://mohamedghilan.com/2011/11/10/my-ummah-will-split-into-73-sects-thats-it/).

Comment: Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: I believe that this answer: http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=149765 answers your question perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of question can muslims study Bible to gain knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Please see (Quran 21:6) and (Quran 21:7)

We can use the Quran as a Furkhan, to separate good from evil and likewise truth from falsehood.  When we are exploring other religions and religious texts for knowledge, if it is in sync with what is in the Quran, and application thereof can enhance our iman and get us closer to Allah, then it is good and true knowledge, otherwise it is false or idle.  The Quran and our prophet (pbuh) were sent as a mercy to all the worlds so we can sort out good and evil no matter where we look.

I agree that you must first be knowledgeable about the Quran before you make the comparisons, or at least ask questions to an alim that does.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?
I mean we already generally study secular wisdom

If there is something divinely inspired by God in their religious texts or perhaps just written down by some intelligent or wise person from his/her own knowledge then you may as well take what is useful and leave the rest

not really sure about the sect thing. I doubt you'll guess the right one. I dont think I will. Probably just a matter of chance there. Just try to have a good heart and live as a good muslim to the best of your ability ie good intentions. Try not to get caught up in religious dogma
:)